# Splice Array at unknown position

Tags: typescript, array-splice

I'm fairly new to Typescript and currently I'm trying to program a Usermanager. My issue is when I want to update a specific user it's not working correctly, as it's always targeting the first user in my array and not the one I actually want to edit.
That is my code:

`const index: number = Number (target.dataset["user"]);`

`userdata.splice(index, 1, new User(mail.value, lastname.value, firstname.value, pwd.value));`

My IDE usually tells me that the first number is "start" and the second "delete count" but in this case it doesn't. So I'm assuming my `index`is not correct somehow. I tried different ways to declare it but nothing works for me.
To be clear what I mean:
e.g. `userdata.splice( start: 0, deleteCount:1, ...)` would be the way my IDE displays this line if I put a number as start index but the way my code is it's:
`userdata.splice (index, deleteCount:1,...)` which is why I'm thinking that my declaration of `index` is not correct.

Comment: Editors typically only label arguments when they are literals, not if they are variables. In your case it labels the `1` but not `index` because the former is a number literal, the latter is a variable. So, the display is unrelated to the problem. If only the first item is deleted, then `Number (target.dataset["user"])` must only produce `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was helpful. At least now I know I was working on the wrong issue.